# NPE with Current Thread Context Class Loader getResourceAsStream(file)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I am trying to get an excel file from my resource folder. This method works fine:

```
public JobOrderGenerator(List<ShopOrder> shopOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Shop-Order.xlsx");

        createJobOrder(shopOrder);

    }
```

Which calls

```
void createJobOrder(List<ShopOrder> shopOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{


        for (ShopOrder shopOrder1 : shopOrder) {
            System.out.println("Inside createJobOrder "+shopOrder1.getPo_number());
            writeToSpecificCell(2, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Po Number
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Part Number
            LocalDate date = shopOrder1.getPo_due_date();
            String dateToString = date.toString();
            writeToSpecificCell(1, 2, sheetNumber, dateToString); //Due_Date
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 5, sheetNumber, Integer.toString(shopOrder1.getPart_quantity())); //Quantity
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.get); //Material
            writeToSpecificCell(8, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPart_decription()); //Part Description
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.getCustomer()); //Customer
            writeToSpecificCell(10, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getMachine_number()); //Machine

            sheetNumber++;

        }

    }
```

This is the culprit below. As you can see I used println statements to figure out what was going on, and what I see in the console is:

```
Inside writeToSpecificCell before try statement 1 0 111
```

right after that is the java.lang.NullPointerException:

Therefore there is something going on with my excel file. I just cannot figure out what. Since I retrieved the it like:

```
inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Shop-Order.xlsx");
```

It should know the location of the file. Since it is in my resource file and not on my class path (so it will be in my jar file) I need to get the file the above way right?

If it matters I am using Intellji Ultimate, still learning the ins and outs, I was a heavy eclipse user.

[image: class path]

-----------Update 1-----------------

```
inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Shop-Order.xlsx");
```

Still getting the same error...

--------Update 2--------------------

```
try{
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

            inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Shop-Order.xlsx");

            if (inputStream == null){

                System.out.println("Inputstream is null....");
            }
```

Just to confirm I also did:

```
inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Shop-Order .xlsx");
```

Just to confirm there was not a space in Shop-Order.xlsx...

It is confirmed that the Inputstream is null, because in the console it is printing:

```
Inputstream is null...
```

From my println statement

The method throwing this null exception is here...

```
 void writeToSpecificCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, int sheetNumber, String value) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        System.out.println("inside writeToSpecificCell method before try statement");

        try {
            System.out.println("inside writeToSpecificCell method inside try statement");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
            }
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
            System.out.println("inside writeToSpecificCell method after try statement");
            workbook.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error in writeToSpecificCell method " + e);

        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println("Null in writeToSpecificCell method");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually throws this exception, and where is the stack trace?

Comment: @EJP Please see update 2.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that you have a space before the extension of the file. Can you see if I am correct? :P

Comment: It certainly looks that way.  And [`getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) returns `An input stream for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found`, the latter part of which is relevant.

Comment: if you use maven, give it a clean and then package

Comment: @Drew1208 In the screenshot you provided, are you telling me that is not a space before `.xlsx`?

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Shop-Order.xlsx")`, this will give you a better chance of getting the appropriate class loader.

As others have mentioned it also appears the file (on disk) has a space right before the `.`, according to your screenshot.

Another culprit may be the build system integration of your IDE, some times refreshing / rebuilding can fix this.

Comment: I already tried this and had the same issue. Being that it is in my resource file which will be in my jar file this is not the preferred way. I am accessing a file within a file and writing to it which is why I used the solution I did.

I refreshed my IDE and it still did not work. Since I am using intellji I selected synchronize with I think is the same for eclipse in reference to refresh.

I am a little glad this was not the issue because I would have felt like a huge dumb!

Comment: I am not sure I quite grok what you said, if these files are getting compiled and placed into the same JAR, then `getClass()` will give you the appropriate class loader as the loader grabbing the bits for the class is the same one holding the resources.

Comment: For giggles, what happens when you do `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Shop-Order .xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the classloader the correct name for this resource is `"/resources/Shop-Order. xlsx"`.